# Sliding Toolbar under UITableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Quick question regarding swift / xcode

I have a UIViewController with a UITableView. The UIViewController has a Navigation bar and a status bar.

My Table rows are musics that play when I tapped the row. I would like to make a second bar appear on the bottom between the Table and the Bottom Bar when a row is clicked. Like apple music app.

[image]

[image]

I've done that using hidden property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.trackControls.hidden = true

    getTrackDataJSON()

}
```

And when Cell is clicked:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let urlString = url
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)!

    do {

        self.trackControls.hidden = false

        avPlayer = AVPlayer(URL:url)

        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    }

    catch {

        print("error")
    }

    avPlayer.play()

}
```

Any Ideas on whow to force the table to fill up the space of the bar when the bar is hidden ? And how to get the second bar to appear sliding from the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlay the second bar over your table view and use content insets to make sure you can scroll all the cells from under de second bar.
Also I would suggest using a `UIView` and not a `UIToolBar`, the `UIView` is less restrictive.

Comment: You mean stretch the table up to the bottom bar? How can use content insets?

Comment: No, you table view is all the way to the bottom of you view, then the `UIView ` with the music control is over the table view. IN the inspector you can then set the content insets. Set you bottom content insets to match the height of the `UIView` that you will use for the music controls.

Comment: Ok I change it to UIView. I set the table all the way down. It's fine. When I click the cell the UIView appears, it's fine. But when the UIView is hidden the table scroll bar is blocked by the UIView. Although the table rows go until the bottom of the view. The scroll bar is not. Any idea?

Comment: There is also a scrollbar inset, but you might have to set this one via code. `tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insest `

Comment: Done thank you. Any idea on how to make the UIView appear from bottom effect (slide up)?

Comment: You could use [`UIView` animation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html)

Comment: Done than and it's working. Only problem is that the I have a label on the UIView that appears first and then the UIView slides in...strange..